# Access denied on editing page in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, access-denied, check-out, check-in

I'm experiencing a strange issue with Sharepoint 2013 at my company. A few users are getting an access denied error when they try to edit a Sharepoint page.  It checks the document out to them but they can't edit the page.

The only workaround I have found so far is for me to discard their check out, edit the page and publish it.  They can then edit the page and publish it.  But if they try to edit it again after that, they get the access denied error.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  All the users have full edit access to the whole site including any image libraries, etc.  Thanks.

Comment: Did you check the access related to the document if that comes from document library and check whether any break in inheritance or any special permission given?

Answer (score 2):

Confirm the following:

- Your masterpage is checked in & published
- Your page layouts are achecked & published
- Your users have read access to the Master Page gallery
- Your service accounts have the appropriate permissions assigned as per [Account permissions and security settings in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc678863.aspx)

The mentioned are the most common issue causers when users can't edit a page despite having required access to the page itself.